# Stop processing event-queue immediately on QThread.exit()

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, pyqt, qthread, event-loop

I am building a Qt GUI application which uses QThread/QObject combinations to act as workers that do stuff outside the main thread.

Via `moveToThread`, the QObject gets moved into the QThread. This way, my worker can have signals (it's a QObject) and slots which are processed in an event loop (provided by QThread).

Now I'd like to make the workers behave in a special way that they stop their thread gracefully whenever a slot in the event loop hits a Python exception.

By testing around a bit, I found that in PyQt5 an exception in a slot causes the whole application to stop, which as far as I read is an intentional change compared to PyQt4 where the excpetion was only printed but the event loop kept running. I read that it's possible to avoid that by monkeypatching your own "excepthook" to `sys.excepthook`, which Qt implements in a way that it stops the interpreter.

So I did that, and so far this works. Moreover, the excepthook enables me to `exit()` my worker when an Exception happens, for which I didn't find a better way elsewhere. I tried subclassing QThread and putting a `try..except` around the call to `exec_()` in the QThread's `run()` method, but it doesn't propagate the exceptions occuring in the event loop... So the only option left would be to put `try..except` blocks inside every single slot, which I wanted to avoid. Or did I miss something here?

Below is an MWE that demonstrates what I have so far. My problem with it is that exiting the thread does not happen immediately when an Exception occurs, demonstrated with the `error` slot which results in a call to `thread.exit()` in the excepthook. Instead all other remaining events in the threads event loop will get executed, here demonstrated by the `do_work` slot that I scheduled behind it. `exit()` just seems to schedule another event to the queue which, as soon as it is processed, then stops the event loop.

How can I get around this? Is there a way to flush the queue of the `QThread`'s events? Can I somehow prioritize the exit?

Or maybe another completely different way to catch exceptions in slots and make the thread stop, without stopping the main program?

**Code**:

```
import sys
import time
from qtpy import QtWidgets, QtCore


class ThreadedWorkerBase(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self.thread.setTerminationEnabled(False)
        self.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.start()

    def schedule(self, slot, delay=0):
        """ Shortcut to QTimer's singleShot. delay is in seconds. """
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(int(delay * 1000), slot)


class Worker(ThreadedWorkerBase):
    test_signal = QtCore.Signal(str)   # just for demo

    def do_work(self):
        print("starting to work")
        for i in range(10):
            print("working:", i)
            time.sleep(0.2)

    def error(self):
        print("Throwing error")
        raise Exception("This is an Exception which should stop the worker thread's event loop.")


#  set excepthook to explicitly exit Worker thread after Exception
sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook
def excepthook(type, value, traceback):
    sys._excepthook(type, value, traceback)
    thread = QtCore.QThread.currentThread()
    if isinstance(thread.parent(), ThreadedWorkerBase):
        print("This is a Worker thread. Exiting...")
        thread.exit()
sys.excepthook = excepthook

# create demo app which schedules some tasks
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
worker = Worker()
worker.schedule(worker.do_work)
worker.schedule(worker.error)    # this should exit the thread => no more scheduling
worker.schedule(worker.do_work)
worker.thread.wait()   # worker should exit, just wait...
```

**Output**:

```
starting to work
working: 0
working: 1
working: 2
working: 3
working: 4
working: 5
working: 6
working: 7
working: 8
working: 9
Throwing error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qt_test_so.py", line 31, in error
    raise Exception("This is an Exception which should stop the worker thread's event loop.")
Exception: This is an Exception which should stop the worker thread's event loop.
This is a Worker thread. Exiting...
starting to work
working: 0
working: 1
working: 2
working: 3
working: 4
working: 5
working: 6
working: 7
working: 8
working: 9
```

**Expectation**:

The output should end after "Exiting...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Qt docs for [`QThread.exit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#exit) are somewhat misleading:

> Tells the thread's event loop to exit with a return code.
>
> After calling this function, **the thread leaves the event loop and
>   returns from the call to QEventLoop::exec()**. The QEventLoop::exec()
>   function returns returnCode.
>
> By convention, a returnCode of 0 means success, any non-zero value
>   indicates an error.
>
> Note that unlike the C library function of the same name, this
>   function does return to the caller -- **it is event processing that
>   stops**. *[emphasis added]*

This suggests that after calling `exit()`, there will be no further processing of the thread's event-queue. But that is not what happens, because `QEventLoop` always calls `processEvents` *before* checking whether it should exit. This means that the event-queue will always be empty when `exec()` returns.

In your example, the single-shot timer will post events to the event-queue of the receiving thread, where the connected slots will eventually be called. So no matter what you do, all those slots will be called *before* the thread finally quits.

A fairly simple way to work around this is to use the [`requestInterruption`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#requestInterruption) feature with a decorator that checks to see if the slot should be called:

```
def interruptable(slot):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.thread.isInterruptionRequested():
            slot(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Worker(ThreadedWorkerBase):
    test_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)   # just for demo

    @interruptable
    def do_work(self):
        print("starting to work")
        for i in range(10):
            print("working:", i)
            time.sleep(0.2)

    @interruptable
    def error(self):
        print("Throwing error")
        raise Exception("This is an Exception which should stop the worker thread's event loop.")

def excepthook(type, value, traceback):
    sys.__excepthook__(type, value, traceback)
    thread = QtCore.QThread.currentThread()
    if isinstance(thread.parent(), ThreadedWorkerBase):
        print("This is a Worker thread. Exiting...")
        thread.requestInterruption()
        thread.exit()
sys.excepthook = excepthook
```

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro. I thought of using a decorator to skip the slots, too, but I would have liked it if I could hide that code somewhere in the base class, to keep the child class as simple as possible. But maybe I can find a way to achieve that in the base's `__init__`...